# undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x1041df24>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, will-paginate

I am trying to paginate an array but not able to do so. Please help

**Below is my controller code:**

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
        def children
            @account = @rest_resource
            @children = []
      User.find_all_by_parentId(@account.user.id).paginate(:page 
      => params[:page], :per_page => 10).each { |eu|
            u = eu.user
            ent = Table2.find(u.login)
            @children << ent unless ent.nil?
            }
        end
end
```

**View File -> children.html.erb:**

```
<%= will_paginate @children %>
<table>
<%= render :partial => 'account', :collection => @children %>
</table>
```

**Partial View ->_account.html.erb:**

```
<tr class="<%= cycle('even', 'odd') %> <% if account.user.is_test? %>Test<% end %>">
    <td><strong><%= link_to h(account.login), account_path(account) %></strong></td>
    <td><% if account.user.test? %>Test <% end %><%= account.attr2 %></td>
    <td>
      <strong><%= account.companyName %></strong><br/>
      <%= account.contact %> - <%= account.Email %> - <%= account.Mobile %>
    </td>
    <td><%=h account.Status %></td>
</tr>
```

This is not working. It says:

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x1041df24>
```

Rails version:

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

JRuby Version:

```
jruby 9.1.17.0 (2.3.3)
```

My app is using:

```
will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

Please could someone help on this

Comment: Please could anyone help.

Comment: can you specify the code where you are using the method total_pages

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing @children as an array and you are passing the same to will_paginate so its throwing an error...try passing like

```
will_paginate @children[0]
```

if you wanna pass each and every instance in that array use

```
@children.each
```

method